# Separate divs with same class name

Tags: jquery, html, containers

Is there a way to separate divs with same class name?
For example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".instancesN").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".instancesNContainer").empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
      $(block).append($("div.instancesNSpecifics").html());
      $(".instancesNContainer").prepend(block);
    }
  });



  /*$(".instancesNContainer").on('change', '.usersvmaddnewdivsN', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
    }
    $(this).parent().append($("div.usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics").html());
    $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").append(block);

  });*/

  $(this).on('change', ".usersvmaddnewdivsN", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
      $(block).append($(".usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics").html());
      $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").append(block);

    }


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='1');" value="1" name='instancesN[]' placeholder="Instances #" class="instancesN form-control" />
<div class="instancesNContainer"></div>
<div class='instancesNSpecifics'>
  <input type='number' min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" name='usersvmaddnewdivsN[]' placeholder="Add new Users" class="form-control usersvmaddnewdivsN" />
  <div class="usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer"></div>
  <div class='usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics'>


    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control usernamevmN" name='usernamevmN[]' placeholder="VM-Username" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My main goal is to create different "Users" and have multiple "VM-Username" divs independent from each other.

See the picture below. I have 2 divs "Add new users" and 4 "VM-Username".My goal is to have 2 divs "Add new users" and the FIRST "VM-Username" just 2 divs, the SECOND "VM-Username" 4 divs and that is not happening!

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish. `this` refers to the `window` object in your code...

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's not correct?

Comment: I can not see two containers with same class.

Comment: Apologies, it refers to `document` because of the `$(function () {` wrapper.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay yeah sorry. I mean , two div's with same class name

Comment: @HereticMonkey do you have any clue or tips?

Comment: Let me repeat: "It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish." [Edit] your question to be more clear about what you think should happen, what's not happening, etc. You may wish to read [ask] and the linked articles for more about what makes a good question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey edited. Please check if it is clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would solve this by taking advantage of selector context (see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to only affect the divs you are interested in.

```js
$(this).on('change', ".usersvmaddnewdivsN", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer", $(this).parent()).empty(); // added: , $(this).parent()
  for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
    var block = $("<div>", {
      class: "block"
    });
    $(block).append($(".usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics").html());
    $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer", $(this).parent()).append(block); // added: , $(this).parent()

  }


});
```

Comment: You saved my life!

Comment: Ha, happy to help!